# Create multiple files based on a pattern

Tags: linux, bash

I am interested in creating multiple files based on a simple pattern.

```
a.kf
b.kf
c.kf
...
fss1.lsk
fss2.lsk
fss3.lsk
...
```

Of course I could use a loop, however I would prefer a more elegant solution. Perhaps using the `tee` command, however I've had difficulty implementing this idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [brace expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html#Brace-Expansion).

```
$ touch {a..c}.kf fss{1..3}.lsk
$ ls
a.kf  b.kf  c.kf  fss1.lsk  fss2.lsk  fss3.lsk
```